# Hive Query Stucks

Tags: hadoop, hive

Initially we are using hive 0.6.0 and queries running fine even if a blocks is corrupted, the query will run and in the end it shows missing blocks in hive 0.6.0.

But after up gradation to hive 0.12.0, hive query with missing blocks hangs.

I even used the -hiveconfive.root.logger=DEBUG,console but no solution.

So anyone faces the same problem?

Comment: Solved by setting hive.input.format from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by setting hive.input.format from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat